# The Android app does not allow pasting into the password field

Tags: bug, android-app

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 running Android 4.4.2 and the SE app version 1.0.43.

When trying to sign in with my Yahoo! account I notice that the clipboard icon in the keyboard becomes grayed out, even though it can be used in the username field.

Comment: Samsung has dedicated keyboard buttons for clipboard operations...?

Comment: @StevenV Yes, in the keyboard is a key for accessing the clipboard. What's really nice is that the clipboard keeps memory of all copies until they are deleted - convenient when needing to copy and paste more than one item.

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.83, Google Keyboard when trying to login with SE account: I could paste into the password field with common approach (long-press on text field, then select "Paste" on the pop-up)... so I guess this is device-dependent issue (in this case, Samsung with its Samsung keyboard and clipboard). Meanwhile, can you use the clipboard on password field *on other apps*? Perhaps this is a limitation set by Samsung itself?

Comment: @AndrewT. You are aware this bug report is over a year and a half old? I have been using after market OS since fall of '14, so can't even say if the bug still exists.

Comment: I'm aware, and I wanted to at least have the updated info on bug reports. Otherwise, the report is going into limbo... but hopefully SE devs can answer/fix this nonetheless.